# When I needed you most vs When I needed you the most

Tags: grammar, word-usage, definite-articles, superlative-degree

This question happens to remind of an oldie song by Randy Vanwarmer, but I was wondering if the two are the same in effect or if they can be different, if at all, or if it's just a matter of preference.

I believe I know the basics of how the word "most" is used. And I did as much as research, including corpus searches, as I could. But I'm still not sure. It's confusing to English learners no matter if it matters or not.

Comment: To me they're equivalent. Also, I think in today's English the version with the article is more common. Perhaps because *the* is often used before superlatives. A Google Ngram "favors" the version without the article but its results seem partially skewed due to a popular song title.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Needed+you+most%2C+needed+you+the+most+&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CNeeded%20you%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bneeded%20you%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bneeded%20You%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNeeded%20You%20Most%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cneeded%20you%20the%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bneeded%20you%20the%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bneeded%20You%20the%20most%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Your theory about the possibility of popular songs biasing Google hits is interesting and persuasive to me. Thank you.

Comment: Songs tend not to worry about sense over rhythm or rhyming. You should probably be cautious before learning English from them!